# Set clipboard with multiline string in python with pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I try to import a multi line string into cliboard and paste it in a webbrowser.
Pasting works but it adds an extra pair of ""

## Import string to cliboard

```
import pandas as pd
multiLineString = """This
multi line string
to clipboard please"""
df=pd.DataFrame([multiLineString])
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)
```

## Send ctrl+v

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options,service=s)
driver.get(url)
...
element = driver.switch_to.active_element
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

## Result:

```
"This
multi line string
to clipboard please"
```

When I try to remove one pair of "" it doesnt recognise it as a string.
Any ideas how I can have the output like this instead:

```
This
multi line string
to clipboard please
```